# Common js modules in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commonjs, react-native

Is it possible to make use of common js modules with react-native?  The use case is sharing logic between a mobile and web version of a react project.

Comment: I think so. Have you tried it? Can you edit your answer to show an error message?

Comment: Yes I'm very interested in the same info. I've got an app and want to share non-ui code between iOS, Web and eventually Android. I can't quite figure out how to 'include' js code where I have all my utility and game logic functions

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I'm new to this too but I think I've figured out how to include js code.  I didn't have to add anything to the standard react native installation.

Create a Library of code:

```
//library.js
exports.foo = function() {

  //Do stuff here
  return "Here";

}
```

Import into another js file:

```
var lib = require("./library.js");
var myString = lib.foo();
```

I found the info from this blog post:

http://0fps.net/2013/01/22/commonjs-why-and-how/